# Which of the following modifiers are valid to apply to a class which is not a nested class?

Tags: java

Which of the following modifiers are valid to apply to a class which is not a nested class?
A)public
B)protected
C)private
D)static

Comment: What does the spec say?  What happens when you try to use them on your classes?

Comment: Please don't make your quiz other people's quiz.  Please include what you think the answers are, and why.  A valid question for this site would be to ask "Is this right?  Here's my reasoning.", not "Answer this for me, doing all the work.".

Comment: [I downvoted because this question shows absolutely zero research effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Answer (score 2):

Only `public` is allowed for top level classes, see

[JLS 8.1.1. Class Modifiers:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1)

> The access modifiers `protected` and `private` pertain only to member classes within a directly enclosing class declaration (§8.5).
>
> The modifier `static` pertains only to member classes (§8.5.1), not to top level or local or anonymous classes.